# View position in recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using a recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager with 3 columns. How can I know in which column my view is?

Comment: f.ex: `position / num_rows_in_the_grid` ?

Comment: that won't give me the right position, because items have different span size.

Comment: you can calculate this information based on getGlobalVisibleRect

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just:

```
column = position % 3
```